# Why does the Christian doctrine seem so far from the Bible?

Tags: sabbath, law, commandments, feasts, circumcision

Upon reading the Bible, I have found that that Christian doctrine differs heavily from the scriptures.

A few of the differences:

1. Circumcision
2. Feast days
3. Following the statutes & judgements
4. Keeping the Sabbath

How is it that Christianity, which is supposed to be followers of Christ, don't seem to follow him at all?

I hold the view that there is only one Christ who brought one doctrine and therefore Christianity should all be following the same teachings. Yet there are many divisions and many varying teachings.

Comment: Why don’t Christians follow Jewish laws and traditions?

Comment: The kingdom was opened up to include Jews (which were the northern tribes which included Judah and Benjamin -- Paul was from the tribe of Benjamin) and Gentiles in the NT. Does that then mean that we should not follow the instructions God gave seemingly to everyone from Adam, Enoch, Noah, Caanan, Israel, Ninevah, etc. What makes us different now?

Comment: Because none of the above-mentioned items have made Jesus Christ be what He was; or, better said, it was not the literal keeping of these symbolic biblical customs that has made Him into the kind of person that He was, but rather a deep spiritual insight into their ultimate mystical meaning and what they actually represent; e.g., being circumcised, as Christ Himself was, will not grant one power over one's physical desires and inclinations, as Christ seemed to possess, by living a celibate life; nor will keeping days of rest grant one the spiritual rest that only comes from a clean heart; etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please have a read of [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071) For this question you really need to pick which perspective whose answers you want. Of course nearly all perspectives will disagree with your assertation that their doctrines differ heavily from the scriptures or that they are not following Christ! It might be better to try to seek to understand what Christians teach rather than declaring that they don't follow Christ without giving any evidence or argument for that declaration.

Comment: This is a big issue in the New Testament, that the apostles have to clarify multiple times. Yet of the answers given none actually cite the parts where the apostles decide the Gentiles are not to be burdened with the old covenant, and their reasoning. We are not done with this question.

Comment: @curiousdannii From my studies, Christ taught the same thing that was in the Old Testament. He said he has not come to destroy the law, but to fulfil what was written about him in the Law, Psalms & Prophets. He also said he came to do the will of the Father. It seems to me that there has been a lot added to come to the conclusion that these things I have mentioned in the question are not to be done.

Comment: @kutschkem If we are not told anywhere to abandon the old covenant (even this is a misnomer since a "new covenant" simply refers to another covenant rather than replacing the previous covenant -- multiple covenants), then why seemingly all the denominations of Christianity work so hard to stop anyone from following the instructions?

Comment: @Observer I don't know any denominations which work hard to stop people following the Jewish Law. Anyway, what's your take on the book of Hebrews?

Comment: @Observer I consider my work done here by voting for reopening, I have no intention of using the comment section as a substitute for an answer. It's too short for that.

Comment: A somewhat [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37374) question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site. I'm assuming you are just starting to investigate Christianity. This is a good question, so I'll try to give you a simple answer.

Most of the Bible, which we call the Old Testament, was written for the Jews. It tells the story of their interaction with God, who gave them all sorts of laws and commands to follow. But one of the things he said was that there would be a person who would come who would set them free.

That person is Jesus Christ, and his story is in the later part of the Bible, the New Testament. The New Testament starts with the Gospels, and is the book of Matthew and everything after. Jesus (speaking for God) tells people that the old laws and commands weren't the point. You didn't have to follow all the old laws like circumcision or feast days, but a new law based around love. He gave his life specifically to free us from it. The old law is useful to know about, but the new law supersedes it.

So if you've been reading only the early part of the Bible, you will find a lot of things that Christians don't do. If you read the later part, especially the Gospels (the books Matthew, Mark, Luke and John) you will understand a lot more. I've simplified this a lot, and if there are specific points you don't understand then feel free to ask about them.

Answer (score 2):

The Differences between the Doctrine of Christ and

1 - Circumcision
2 - Feast days
3 - Following the statutes & judgements
4 - Keeping the Sabbath

---

The four items mentioned in the question pertain to the first humanity, that of Adam and his seed. By a conspiracy involving Serpent, woman and man - in Eden - the first humanity partook, willingly, of the knowledge of good and evil which God had warned would lead to spiritual death, immediately.

As a result, humanity was judged accordingly and, through physical death, was condemned to return to the dust from whence it came, having failed of its purpose : a purpose which, through the immediacy of its failure, it never even discovered what it was, never mind actually rose to that purpose to fulfil it.

This is seen in the concept of the [cherubim](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiZWxtb250cHVibGljYXRpb25zfGd4OjNlYWMyNDEyNWFiY2E4MzE) which appear, in Eden, when humanity fails, and are ‘settled’ to await another opportunity of realisation, an opportunity promised by God when a seed will arise through woman (not man) and will bruise the serpent from above, that is to say, humanity being raised above angelic power in a new creation.

In Christ, there is a new creation, new heavens and a new earth. In Christ there is a New Testament, an ‘everlasting testament‘. In Christ there is redemption. In Christ there is ‘restitution’ as Peter calls it. In Christ there is ‘restoration’ as Paul calls it.

But not a restitution to what was set out in Israel, with sacrifices and feasts and circumcision and a Sabbath. All those things, and many more, were mere pictures set forth on earth, within Israel, as a testimony to the whole world of what would be when that promised seed came, which God promised after the first humanity failed.

The realisation and fulfillment of that promise is the birth of Jesus Christ, born of the virgin Mary. And his subsequent sufferings, death, resurrection and his ascension to the Throne of God in the heavens, above all principalities and powers, seated at the right hand of God, in humanity.

The redemption, the restitution and the restoration are to what was always in the mind of God, ‘before the foundation of the world ', ‘before the mountains were formed' and 'before there was a sea'.

And in that restoration there is a new humanity, born ‘of water and of spirit’, ‘born anew’, ‘born again’, ‘born from above’, ‘born of God’. It is described in each of these different aspects in scripture.

That humanity is subject to Christ, subject to a New Testament, subject to a New Creation.

It is not subject to the first man, Adam. It is not subject to the Serpent.

It is a ‘new thing‘.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, there are many other things that were part of being God's people that are not required anymore under the New Covenant. This is why you can buy a bible that is just the New Testament - to be blunt, the concept goes - no one cares about the old stuff anymore and so the NT is all I need to read.

The entire Old T. pointed to the New that would be formed in Christ. This was foreknown by God from before He made the 'world'.

> ...he(Jesus) was foreknown before the creation of the world... 1 Pet 1:20

All the things they did, that you mentioned, are part of the what led up to Christ.

> Therefore no one is to act as your judge in regard to food or drink or in respect to a festival or a new moon or a Sabbath day — 17 things which are a mere shadow of what is to come; but the substance belongs to Christ. Col 2:16

They are not now somehow 'wrong', they are replaced by something far grander. The endless sacrifices of OT are replaced by the one sacrifice of Christ (for eg).

Some of the Feast days are still valid today as they have a future component that is yet to be realised. (Some might say they all do, but that is another topic) But they are not a Holy DAY as they once were, but a reminder of the plan of God He has revealed through them.

The bottom line is - we are made righteous not by doing things, but by faith in what Jesus has accomplished for us. We still 'do things', but only as a response to God's spirit in us.

> For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus has set you free from the law of sin and of death. Rom 8:2